# Alternative to Google Play when publishing Android game app (.apk)?

Tags: android, publishing, business, accessibility

In order to register as a game developer and publisher of the Android app for Google Play Developer account, you must pay around $100. But what if there's a tight budget, especially for indie game developers from the start? I want to know where can I find alternatives to publish and promote Android game apps with no registration cost. It is something like a stepping stone.

Comment: You only need to pay $25. It's still could be a lot of money, but definitely less, than $100

Comment: Unfortunately, service recommendations are not on topic here.

Comment: @Bálint Oh! I see...approximation is too large to guess. I exactly remember that right price now.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I see. Then, there is no other good option but to invest it.

Answer (score 1):

You can host the *.apk* anywhere online and just let the users download and install it manually. The down sides of this approach are many, for example discoverability (most people find *all* their applications *only* in Google Play) and lower level of trust (people are less likely to trust something outside of Google Play).

Having said that, this approach is used successfully by some apps, notably some betting companies do it this way due to Google Play's stance on gambling apps.

Comment: Come to think of it, if improvise a download website to promote an app, there are some penalties. For example, let's say an Android game app that has an ads attached such as AdMob. According to AdMob, usingthe live ads will result to a penalty for suspension. The only choice is to set a price tag per download via website programming skills in a way to promote or asking for donations (chances will be a hit-or-miss as most users tempted to download for free anyways).